Kernel Unknown in JupyterLab on MAC - Don't know how to resolve
Trying to assist friend that cannot get JupyterLab to work on MacBook Air.  I am new at this so appreciate the patience.  Everything I understand so far has been learned in the last two days researching so not very knowledgeable about coding right into Terminal or finding executables so hopefully there is some handholding someone can do with us.
All I can describe is that we have Python on the Mac somewhere and have attempted to install and uninstall Anaconda/JupyterLab multiple times and within JupyterLab we have the orange "Kernel Unknown" rectangle persistently in the right corner.  It's not like it is an error and I can click and do a traceback to share anything with you all (I just learned about %tb today btw).
Below the Kernel Unknown rectangle it says  Python 3 (ipykernel) and a lightning bolt.
Anything that is typed into the prompt line in Jupyter - literally nothing happens.
In the Kernel menu, we see
Start Preferred Kernel
check mark   Python 3 (ipykernel)
Use No Kernel
No Kernel
Use Kernel from Preferred Session
Use Kernel from Other Session
Untitled3.ipynb
He has tried creating multiple sessions and nothing happens.  We are afraid to uninstall python given the worry of truly removing all files but also accidentally grabbing Mac OS files.  (Currently on macOS Big Sur Version 11.7.10).
The only other thing to offer is at the top of the Jupyter session it is an untitled session and it says "Last Checkpoint 21 days ago".
Tried installing and uninstalling and can't get it to work.

There's no details here for anyone to be able to help you much. You just seem to have cycled over doing the same thing over and over (though providing no specifics on how you really did that), probably exacerbating the problem(s). See here for information about JupyterLab Desktop. It is supposed to be easiest way to get started with JupyterLab these days. Read that on how to use JupyterLab Desktop as its project management set up expects you to use it as described.

For other maybe finding this because it mentions Anaconda...If you did want to use the Anaconda Distribution, install that and use the Anaconda Navigator to launch Python and test it works. And then try launching Jupyter from there. Read the getting started material as use of Anaconda requires a level of learning and understanding environment management. The top two answers here cover how to install and link individual ipkernels to evironments and link them to Jupyter.

Thank you for the comments.  No surprises that I'm not a coder, so details are difficult to offer.  But as I've learned (and you may giggle), Geeksquad/Genius Bar/local Computer Shop and even the local College IT department haven't been able to help so I only knew to come here.  Forgive the naiveté and appreciate the help very much.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Understood. Main reason is to let you know so that you understand why your post may not get traction. Everybody starts somewhere. By the way, if what you are doing doesn't require major computational power, there is JupyterLite, too. This runs in your local computer's browser, so in some ways, like saving your notebook in your local file storage, you have to treat it like a remote computer but actually isn't, which can be important for security considerations. If what you doing doesn't require security and only requires temporary access to Jupyter, there is MyBinder-served sessions. More on...

 that can be found here. I refer you to the bottom of my post here though for links current for JupyterLite use. I should add that the current JupyterLite has limitations for things like using input() and network connections that usually can be worked around with special approaches or considerations.
